# jxls can't read cell on spreadsheet email hyperlink

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jxls

Hi I am using jxls for reading data from excel file to java bean. I got an issue while mapping. There is a column F2 called email in the spreadsheet which is a email hyperlink. When I try to run I get net.sf.jxls.reader.XLSDataReadException: Can't read cell F2 on Subscribers spreadsheet and my mapping for the cell is  subscriber.email . Is there something to do with the mapping? Can you please let me know how to get out of this exception. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post the relevant section from your XML mapping file?

Comment: Hi Jamie Here is the XML

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><workbook>
   <worksheet name="Sheet1">
    <section startRow="0" endRow="2">
    <mapping cell="A2">subscriber.firstName</mapping>
    <mapping cell="B2">subscriber.middleName</mapping>
    <mapping cell="C2">subscriber.lastName</mapping>
    <mapping cell="D2">subscriber.birthDate</mapping>
    <mapping cell="E2">subscriber.gender</mapping>  
    <mapping cell="F2">subscriber.heightInInches</mapping>  
    <mapping cell="G2">subscriber.weightInPounds</mapping>  
    </section>
  </worksheet>
</workbook>

Comment: Also do you know if there is a way to read excel data and convert to java objects when number of columns are not known.

Answer (score 0):

Your cell F2, in your mapping file, is for subscriber.heightInInches, which I presume is an int. If this contains an email address in your spreadsheet, JXLS can't load this into an int.

Answer (score 0):

you just check by commenting email column(F2) if it will parse then check something mismatch is there in either model class or in xml file